# How can I get days between two dates in the same column?

Tags: mysql

I have table structure like where Loanid is Foreign Key

```
TranID  LOANID       TRANSDATE  
2          2          2013-05-01     
13         2          2013-05-10     
14         2          2013-05-15    
6          5          2013-05-01   
7          5          2013-06-10     
8          5          2013-06-14   
9          5          2013-07-01    
10         5          2013-07-10
```

i need a query to calculate Days between  like below .

```
TranID  LOANID       TRANSDATE    DAYS_BETWEEN
2          2          2013-05-01    9 
13         2          2013-05-10    5 
14         2          2013-05-15    0
6          5          2013-05-01   41
7          5          2013-06-10    4 
8          5          2013-06-14   17
9          5          2013-07-01    9
10         5          2013-07-10    0
```

Comment: maybe, you agree with `2          2          2013-05-01    0  |  
13         2          2013-05-10    9` ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a self join, using MIN to get the next date.

```
SELECT t1.tranid, 
        t1.loanid, 
        t1.transdate
        DATEDIFF(IFNULL(MIN(t2.transdate), t1.transdate),  t1.transdate) AS days
FROM some_table t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN some_table t2
ON t1.loanid = t2.loan_id
AND t1.transdate < t2.transdate
GROUP BY t1.tranid, 
        t1.loanid, 
        t1.transdate
```

Comment: What doesn't seem right? Only thing I can see is the order, but you haven't specified what order you require.